# Is it possible to use a ClassLoader to load a class implementing a package private interface loaded by another ClassLoader?

Tags: java, android, classloader, dexclassloader

I have two separate ClassLoaders, one have loaded the package private interface A:

```
package com.example;    

interface A {}
```

And I have another class loader created from a dex file containing class B:

```
package com.example;

class B implements A {
     B() {}
}
```

The second class loader is an `InMemoryDexLoader` which receives another ClassLoader as parent that can load the interface A, however it does **not** contain class B. (The `byteBuffer` contains the dex file containing the definition for class B).

```
ClassLoader bLoader = new InMemoryDexClassLoader(byteBuffer, parentLoader);
bLoader.loadClass("com.example.B").newInstance();
```

At this point I am - quite regrettably - receiving an `IllegalAccessOperation`. Even though the two classes are in the same package, they have been loaded by separate loaders, and this seems to make their package relation null and void. Is there some way around this?